# Use MKReversegeoCoder with native application

Tags: iphone, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have used MKReverseGeocoder from iPhone sdk for my application without using mapview of iphone sdk,but my application has map view which i am getting from google api passing Address.

But in order to get address i am doing as follows :

1. Current location(Latitude/Longitude) with CLLocation library
2. MKReversegeocoder API of iphone sdk to get address from latitude/longitude

Sending this address to google maps api to get the map

So my doubt is whether my procedure of using iphone MKReversegeocoder voilating the rules of google terms & conditions as i am not using mapview of iphone sdk

References:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html

Awaiting for anyone valuable help to clarify my doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not state which of Google's map API's you use for getting the map. According to clause 10.8 you may only use the static API if you access it from a web browser. If you are using any of the other API's you should be fine. You are not required to get the map through Apple's map API (clause 1.1, 1.3 and others) but may use additional Google API's for content.

Clause 10.12 states that you must only use the data in conjunction with a Google map. It doesn't however state which Google map API you must use for this (no requirements for using Apple API), so as long as you use at least on of the map API's this should be fine.

I'm not a lawyer by trade or profession, but to my best of knowledge and understanding of their terms you should be home safe.